# ¿Se puede colocar dos Layout diferentes en un mismo RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, layout, adapter

Para poner el ejemplo de un chat. Los mensajes los coloco en un RecyclerView, y cada elemento del RecyclerView es un Layout que esta compuesto por un cardView en donde va el nombre, hora y mensaje.

Ahora bien, un usuario va a elegir una opción en donde habrá dos botones, esta opcion la quiero colocar dentro del RecyclerView (Algo así como cuando envías un contacto por Whatsapp).Claramente este es otro Layout diferente al del mensaje.
Mi pregunta es si puedo agregar otro Layout diferente en ese RecyclerView, y como puedo hacerlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No Agrego codigo ya que no he hecho eso, quiero saber si puedo lograr colocar ambos tipos de "Mensajes" dentro del chat

Comment: Esto se puede lograr obteniendo el `typeview` y a la hora de inflarlos en el `onBindViewHolder` preguntas el tipo y segun eso inflas la `view` que deseas.

Comment: Me marie con la ultima parte de las opciones, podrias explciarlo de otra manera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se puede, necesitarias usar como dice Julian distintos [ViewTypes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)), que vienen siendo distintas vistas que vos inflas en tu onBindViewHolder, recordemos que el onBindViewHolder infla las vistas con lo que le pasas y en el onCreateViewHolder devolvemos la vista que tiene que ser creada.

Aca te dejo un ejemplo de como lo deberias hacer

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        //Los elementos del Recycler del ejemplo
        public TextView place;
        public ImageView pics;

        //Aca usamos el header del recycler que vendria siendo el titulo y la descripcion (viewType = 0)
        public TextView name, description;

        //El constructor, dependiendo al viewType que se le asigne va a declarar los distintos elementos a inflar en cada vista
        public ViewHolder(View v, int viewType) {
            super(v);
            if (viewType == 0) {
                name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                decsription = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
            } else if (viewType == 1) {
                place = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.place);
                pics = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.pics);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                         int viewType)
    {
        View v;
        ViewHolder vh;
        // Creamos la vista nueva
        switch (viewType) {
            case 0: //Este va a ser el header que definimos arriba
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_welcome, parent, false);
                vh = new ViewHolder(v,viewType);
                return  vh;
            default: //Esta es la lista normal con los lugares y las imagenes
                v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_picture, parent, false);
                vh = new ViewHolder(v, viewType);
                v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, nextActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("ListNo",mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(v));
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
                return vh;
        }
    }

    //hacemos override de getItemViewType para poder inflar distintas vistas
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int viewType = 1; //Default es 1
        if (position == 0) viewType = 0; //si es 0 es la vista del header
        return viewType;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        //position == 0 significa que es la vista del header
        if (position == 0) {
            holder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"name clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            holder.description.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"description clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            //Esto significa que ya estamos mas aya de la posicion 0 donde se muestra el header, aca ya empezamos a mostrar la imagen con el texto de place
        } else if (position > 0) {
           holder.place.setText(mDataset[position]);
            if (position % 2 == 0) {
               holder.pics.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic1));
            }
            if (position % 2 == 1) {
                holder.pics.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic2));
            }

        }
    }
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: No me funcionó del todo, en el método getItemViewType() el parámetro position me lo toma como el id del mensaje, osea en ese caso el primer mensaje, el que tiene el id 0 me lo muestra con el otro Layout, lo que quiero es que ese otro Layout me lo muestre solamente cuando le de a un botón que tengo en la pantalla, de resto todos son mensajes

Comment: [Actualización]: Ya lo solucioné, no necesitaba ese método, simplemente le mandaba desde el Activity del chat el tipo de mensaje que era. Gracias por la ayuda.